# Using diamond operator in Java 7

Tags: java, generics

Prior to Java 7 the syntax below was used to create an ArrayList,

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
```

But since Java 7 we can omit the generic type in the constructor i.e.,

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
```

But when I tried to do something like,

```
ArrayList<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,4,5.5,6.6,7.7));
```

I get an error, but when I mention the generic type on right side i.e.,

```
ArrayList<Number> nums = new ArrayList<Number>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5.5,6.6,7.7));
```

The code works perfectly. What could be the reason behind this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I can't pull up specific passages from the JLS that changed between Java 7 and 8 to support this, so this is a comment, but if memory serves Java 8 expanded the types of inference that could be performed, I believe by allowing supertypes to be searched as well and/or by taking additional context into account. Your third code snippet compiles without complaint in Java 8.

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList` is a generic method, so technically, it can be invoked as:

```
Arrays.<Number> asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Even before Java 7, the language could do some limited inference to eliminate this when the left-hand side was known, as in

```
final List<Number> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

It looks like you stumbled onto an edge case where the two types of inference cannot be successfully combined, where the diamond inference and generic method inference don't get along. I'm sure [the JLS sheds more light on this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) as well if you were to dig through it.

Answer (score 3):

Java Generics are Invariant whereas Arrays are Covariant.

If generics in Java were covariant, if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `List[A]` is a subtype of `List[B]`. But it is not the case in Java. ( Scala has a covariance implementation. In Scala, if `B` extends `A`, then `List[B]` extends `List[A]`)

But `String[]` is subtype of `Object[]`

Hence an `ArrayList<Double>` cannot be cast to an `ArrayList<Number>` as in your case.