# ArrayList not allowed with diamond sign in Java 1.6

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a project that still uses Java 1.6. In java 1.7, I can write like his

```
public ASTParseUnit(final IParserSelector parserSelector) {
    Data = new ArrayList <>(); // this is error in java 1.6
    this.parserSelector = parserSelector;
}
```

How can I representate statement in Java 1.6 form this code `Data = new ArrayList <>();`  ?

Thanks

Solved. Sorry, this is an old project from antoher hands. 
now the code looked like this

```
List<ReportChart> Data;
ReportChart detailChart;

public ASTParseUnit(final IParserSelector parserSelector) {
    Data = new ArrayList <ReportChart>();
    this.parserSelector = parserSelector;
}
```

Comment: By filling in the proper type arguments, perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

By specifying, in between the `<>`, what the `ArrayList` is of.

```
Data = new ArrayList <ObjectType>();
```

Comment: And a link to where this is documented as new in Java 7: http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the plus features of Java 7 was the diamond operator. That allows us to convert:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

To this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
```

Aditional to AntonH answer, you can use the old friend Guava. That allows you to do:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = Maps.newHashMap();
```

In your case would be:

```
Data = new ArrayList <ObjectType>(); // Java 6 (AntonH example)
Data = Lists.newArrayList();         // Guava example
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 does not support the diamond operator. [It was introduced on Java 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_7#Java_SE_7_.28July_28.2C_2011.29). See this question for related [uses before and after Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334953/using-diamond-operator-in-java-7).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Philip Of course it does ! It solves the issue explained in the OP... >.<